# relatively new programmer interested in using Celery, is this the right approach

Tags: python, mysql, celery

Essentially I have a large database of transactions and I am writing a script that will take some personal information and match a person to all of their past transactions.

So I feed the script a name and it returns all of the transactions that it has decided belong to that customer.

The issue is that I have to do this for almost 30k people and the database has over 6 million transaction records.

Running this on one computer would obviously take a long time, I am willing to admit that the code could be optimized but I do not have time for that and I instead want to split the work over several computers.  Enter Celery:

My understanding of celery is that I will have a boss computer sending names to a worker computer which runs the script and puts the customer id in a column for each transaction it matches.

Would there be a problem with multiple worker computers searching and writing to the same database?

Also, have I missed anything and/or is this totally the wrong approach?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why not create a temporary table of the 30k people and join it to the transaction records?  Has this approach proven too slow?

Comment: As the data is now there is no key to link customers to transactions, the script has to figure out who was involved in what transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there wouldn't be any problem multiple worker computers searching and writing to the same database since MySQL is designed to be able to handle this. Your approach is good.

Comment: If it takes one computer 3 minutes for a single name, what will the performance be like if I have 100 computers working with the same DB?